# How to make html views reusable in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a PHP developer, and I'm new to Angular.

You may know that with php, you can split html content into partials such as head.html, footer.html, so that they can be reused in other places.

But in Angular, there's only one  in each app, and I can only use one template file with a router rule.

Is there any solution? Thanks.

Comment: This is not correct "there's only one in each app".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) or custom [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to include partial content within a particular page.